# finite dimensional algebras without bound quiver representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, quiver

(1) For the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\mathbb{C}$, ($\mathbb{R}$ real number field, $\mathbb{C}$ complex number field) there is no quiver $Q $ such that
$\mathbb{C}\cong
\mathbb RQ/\mathcal{I}$ with $\mathcal{I}$ an admissible ideal of $\mathbb{R}Q$, why?

(2) Let $A$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra$\left[
                                     \begin{array}{cc}
                                       \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C} \\
                                       0 & \mathbb{R} \\
                                     \end{array}
                                   \right]$. Then $A$ is a basic $\mathbb{R}$-algebra,  but there is no quiver $Q $ such that
$A\cong
\mathbb{R}Q/\mathcal{I}$ with $\mathcal{I}$ an admissible ideal of $\mathbb{R}Q$. why?

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old question. But I got a little confused: assertion (2) would not be a contradiction with the fact that every finite-dimensional basic algebra over a perfect field is a quotient of a path algebra [cf. Corollary 4.1.11 of D. J. Benson's book "Representations and Cohomology"] ?

Answer (score 3):

I can answer question (1) - $\mathbb{C}$ has exactly one (non-zero) idempotent, and zero radical, so the quiver $Q$ in question must have exactly one vertex, and no arrows. Then there are no non-zero admissible ideals, but $\mathbb{R}Q\cong\mathbb{R}$.

I haven't worked it all the way through, but I imagine a similar approach works for the second question - find the idempotents and the radical to write down what $Q$ has to be, and then try to understand why no possible ideals give you the right quotient.